# c# asp.net core Bearer error="invalid_token"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

I have a valid token but unable to get my Authentication part working. Why is a seemingly valid token getting a token `invalid token` error?

---

This is the code for login which returns a valid token if proper credentials are used. While, in contrast invalid login credentials elicit a `401 Unauthorized`.

###### Login Code

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
    {
        var userFromRepo = await _repo.Login(userForLoginDto.Username.ToLower(), userForLoginDto.Password);

        if (userFromRepo == null)
            return Unauthorized();

        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userFromRepo.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.Username)
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = creds
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return Ok(new {
            token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
        });
}
```

Then the next part is to limit the access. The user should be logged in first in order to view actual content.

###### Authentication Setup Code

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>{
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                };
            });
```

Enabled by the call

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

I also enabled the `[Authorize]` in the Values Controller

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
```

This is the screenshot of postman when I attempt a call

[image]

I have pasted the token received from login, but it gives me this error

> WWW-Authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid"

Why does the error give me `invalid token` if the token is from the login and how can it be resolved?

Comment: this error i had if i omited contentType

Comment: @daremachine. sorry i don't understand the contentType. Can you please expand. I'm from WPF. I don't really understand

Comment: Can you show your api/values, did you put any authorization policy on that?

Comment: @PSK yes. The authorization policy is enabled. Kindly check the post. I updated it and forgot to mention it. Sorry

Comment: @Ramonbihon I wonder how did u resolve this issue?

Answer (score 39):

I had this issue in `dotnet 6` after update to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer v6.0.0+`

As fix: Install `nuget` package `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt Version="6.16.0"`

Comment: Thank you! How in the world did you figure this out?

Comment: Thank you! I would like to know too @adam0101

Comment: See more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579279/unauthorized-invalid-token-when-authenticating-with-jwt-bearer-token-after-upd

Comment: Wow had been scratching my head for 2 days. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Wow, it worked, I wasted my whole day, thanks for the fix.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I can confirm this fix works.

Comment: Much appreciated, i've been troubleshooting this on and off for several days. Well done.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem where a .net Core 3 API would not authenticate its own tokens.

The solution for me was in Startup/Configure(), to put app.UseAuthentication() before app.UseAuthorization().

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();
 }
```

Comment: that was my problem.

Comment: This was my issue as well, apparently the order matters because of how the pipeline is setup. I need to spend more time on internals.

Answer (score 8):

I recently did similar thing using JWT token which is working fine with Postman. My approach for creating the JWT token is little different, **In your case the problem can be due to not specifying the** **issuer** and **audience**.

Can you try like following.

```
   var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.WindowsAccountName, this.User.Identity.Name)
    };
    Claim userIdClaim = new Claim("UserId", "12345");
    claims.Add(userIdClaim);
    //Avoid Replay attack
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "User GivenName"));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, "UserSurname"));
    claims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));

    string[] roles = "Role1,Role2,Role23".Split(",");

    foreach (string role in roles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(role, ""));
    }

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("veryVerySecretKey"));
    var key1 = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ASEFRFDDWSDRGYHF")); 
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var encryptingCreds = new EncryptingCredentials(key1, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128KW, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128CbcHmacSha256);
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var t = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken();
    var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken("http://localhost:61768/", "http://localhost:61768/"
        , new ClaimsIdentity(claims)
        , expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
        , signingCredentials: creds
        , encryptingCredentials :encryptingCreds
        , notBefore:DateTime.Now
        ,  issuedAt:DateTime.Now);
    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

And my `ConfigureServices` looks like

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
             {
                 options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                 options.SaveToken = true;
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     ValidateIssuer = true,
                     ValidateAudience = true,
                     ValidateLifetime = true,
                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                     ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:61768/",
                     ValidAudience = "http://localhost:61768/",
                     TokenDecryptionKey= new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ASEFRFDDWSDRGYHF")),
                     IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("veryVerySecretKey")),
                     ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                 };
             });
```

Note: Change the issuer and the key appropriately.

Comment: i haven't tried your solution but thank you for your time. The solution is ValidateAudience = false in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The error that you received is related to audience, you should either include a ValidAudience or set ValidateAudience to false in your options.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
          };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Please note that the order in the Configure function.
`app.usemvc ();` should be at the bottom. Like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ram Kumaran (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54396550/8210755) answer works for me, It could have happend after update to net core 3.1 or after update IdentityServer to 4.3.1

I've remplaced commented code with AddJwtBearer

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            //.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            //{
            //    options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerUrl").Value;
            //    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            //    options.ApiName = "api1";
            //});
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
             {
                 o.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerUrl").Value;
                 o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                 o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     ValidateAudience = false
                 };
             });
```

Usefull doc ref:
https://docs.identityserver.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/
Using ValidateAudience in false like proof of concept

Answer (score 0):

In my case (with Keycloak) I added a new realm and forgot to change the urls for Authorization and Jwt bearer metadata. They were still pointing to the old realm. I changed the realm name from portal to test-portal and the token supplied was not correct because it was still coming from the portal realm.

Taken from my appsettings.json:

```
"AuthorizationUrl": "https://my.keycloak.id.provider/realms/test-portal/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
"JwtBearerMetadataAddress": "https://my.keycloak.id.provider/realms/test-portal/.well-known/openid-configuration"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Looking for a similar issue but not this one,

in your appsettings.json you need to add a JWT Section and use them to validate the issuer and audience of the token to more safe tokens

if you look at the description of error : The audience is invalid

```
"BearerToken": {
"Issuer": "the api host",
"Audience": "who use the token",
"Key": "a key to validate your token",
"AccessTokenExpirationMinutes": 25,
"RefreshTokenExpirationMinutes": 50
```

},

and when you adding the token Descriptor you have to add the issuer and the audience in it

```
var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Issuer = _configuration.Value.Issuer,
                Audience = _configuration.Value.Audience,
                Expires = Clock.UtcNow.ExpiresInMinutes(_configuration.Value.AccessTokenExpirationMinutes),
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(authSignInKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
            };
```

and in your startup class (.NET 5 or before) or Program (.NET 6)

you need to add authentication service like this to verify token

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
      options.SaveToken = true;
      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          ValidateIssuer = true,
          ValidateAudience = true,
          ValidateLifetime = true,
          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
          ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["BearerToken:Issuer"],
          ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["BearerToken:Audience"],
          IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(builder.Configuration["BearerToken:Key"])),
      };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me my parameters to the JwtSecurityToken constructor were not correct. There are some nullable parameters on the constructor so I needed to define which was which. For example I had...

```
new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, audience, claims, 
                     expires, signingCredentials: credentials);
```

This fixed it.

```
new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, audience, claims, 
                     expires: expires, signingCredentials: credentials);
```

Probably a long shot for others to run into this, but hey, it happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

Tolerated by downgrading `AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` from version 8.0.0 to 7.0.15

and keep looking for the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52388

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35529149)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My WebApi is hosted in IIS environment with Https protocol and I create self-signed certification according to https://dotnetplaybook.com/custom-local-domain-using-https-kestrel-asp-net-core/

The problem is resolved by import the created pfx into Certificates - Local Computer -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities
and Certificates - Local Computer -> Personal (for IIS Sites SSL)