# Unauthorized (Invalid Token) when authenticating with JWT Bearer Token after update to .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

After updating the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` from version 3.1.14 to 6.0.1, requests with authentication fail with 401 Unauthorized `invalid token`.

What needs to be changed with the new package version?

Comment: Downgrading the Nuget package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens 6.18.0 -> 6.10.0 has helped me with Method not found Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.InternalValidators.ValidateLifetimeAndIssuerAfterSignatureNotValidatedJwt

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. Adding an event handler (`JwtBearerEvents`), the failure could be identified as a `MissingMethodException`:

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.InternalValidators.ValidateLifetimeAndIssuerAfterSignatureNotValidatedJwt(Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken, System.Nullable`1<System.DateTime>, System.Nullable`1<System.DateTime>, System.String, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters, System.Text.StringBuilder)'.
```

with stack trace

```
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()",
```

Simply adding the current version of `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` solved the problem.

---

Update: Please also note the comment by @Rubenisme below.

Comment: Thanks, your fix works, and was easy to search for, but you can also do something else. This issue is identified here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1792 and as ericbl states there, it can also be fixed by removing an explicit reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens. I tested both fixes on my application.

Comment: I confirm that removing the explicit reference works and imho it is the best solution.

Comment: Both fixes work. However, if you're unable to remove explicit reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens then adding explicit for System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt will solve the issue. 
Guess those 2 override each other or something

Comment: Which `JwtBearerEvents` event did you tap into to get the `MissingMethodException`?  I'm getting a similar error, but your solution didn't fix it.  I would like to get some more detail and this seems like the best approach.  I tried the `OnAuthenticationFailed` method, but it never fires.

Comment: @MattRuwe I can't remember which one exactly fired, but I just tapped into all possible events.

Comment: @MoB. I did try looking at all of the events, but didn't see anything worthwhile.  FWIW, the `OnTokenValidated` event is firing, but I still get a 401 response.

Comment: @MattRuwe If you run the code in debug and have a console output, set the log level to debug and you'll see the missing method exception in there too. I find that easier than wiring up event handlers.

Comment: I have installed System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to solve the same and error gone from my local machine but I'm still getting the same error on server how can I solve it I am using devops to release my code.

Answer (score 13):

Although I guess you found the right solution, but I thought my answer might be a help for some problems.

After spending a whole day investigating on the same problem and finding no solutions, I decided to upgrade these libraries to match same version: `6.16.0` *(on Mar 23, 2022)*

- `Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens`
- `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging`
- `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols`
- `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect`
- `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`

And the **problem disappeared**.

Comment: It worked for me, i had to update all this references to the same version, thanks

Comment: This worked for me too.
For some strange reasons, the previously referred versions were not identical, and I had to force them as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I had a same problem in a project that I upgraded it from .NetCore 2.2 to .Net 6.0.
I also update all packages and so on...

In my case I remove below reference from my project and it works fine!

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.25.0" />
```

For more details read this from [here (on GitHub)](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1792#issuecomment-993393946).

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was slightly different but related so I'll add it here in case anyone gets here looking for a solution to `Method not found: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.BaseConfiguration Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters.get_Configuration()`

There seems to be a bug with `Microsoft.Identity.Web 1.19.0`. Downgrading to 1.18.0 fixed it for me.