# Problems with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 401 unauthorised in .NET 6 ASP.NET Core

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, adal

I have had a problem recently in my .NET 6 ASP.NET Core web api project. I use identity server 4 and in the api client project, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer just following the getting started documentation on the identity server 4 site, nothing complicated.

A class library that my API referenced included the latest version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens. I wasn't calling any of this code, just including the nuget package was enough for the API to consistently return 401's. This took 4 days to find reconstructing my apps from scratch, when just removing this package (and the method that called it that wasn't being called) fixed the problem, so I'm raising this question to find out:-

- Has anybody had similar problems?
- Am I doing anything wrong?
- Just what is the problem and who can I report it to?

I contacted the identity server 4 people and they said it was something to do with package versioning but I can't see that, the Jwt package doesn't have a dependancy according to visual studio.

I have tagged adal in the hope that somebody at Microsoft sees this also.

Code from API as requested:
Program.cs

```
public static class Program
{
    private static string _elmahApiKey = string.Empty;
    private static string _elmahLogId = string.Empty;

    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var builder = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .WriteTo.ElmahIo(new ElmahIoSinkOptions(_elmahApiKey, new Guid(_elmahLogId))
              {
                  MinimumLogEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Warning,
              })
              .CreateLogger();

            builder.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            //Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            Log.Fatal(ex, $"Host terminated unexpectedly with {ex}");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                var builtConfig = config.Build();

                _elmahApiKey = builtConfig["ElmahIo:ApiKey"];
                _elmahLogId = builtConfig["ElmahIo:LogId"];

                var keyVaultName = builtConfig["KeyVaultName"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultName))
                {
                    var secretClient = new SecretClient(
                            new Uri($"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
                            new DefaultAzureCredential()
                        );

                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient,
                          new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions
                          {
                              Manager = new KeyVaultSecretManager(),
                              ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
                          });
                }
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseSerilog().UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
                {
                    logging.AddElmahIo(options =>
                    {
                        options.ApiKey = context.Configuration["ElmahIo:ApiKey"];
                        options.LogId = new Guid(context.Configuration["ElmahIo:LogId"]);
                    });
                });
            });
```

#if DEBUG
builder = builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
config.AddJsonFile("secrets.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
});
#endif

```
        return builder;
    }

}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddHealthChecks()
                .AddCheck("sql", () =>
                {
                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                        }
                        catch (SqlException ex)
                        {
                            return HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("Failed", ex);
                        }
                    }
                    return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();
                });

            services.AddElmahIo(o =>
            {
                o.ApiKey = Configuration["ElmahIo:ApiKey"];
                o.LogId = new Guid(Configuration["ElmahIo:LogId"]);
            });

            services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
            {
                o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            });

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddControllers(o =>
            {
                o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());
            })
                .AddJsonOptions(o =>
                {
                    o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;//new PropertyNamingPolicyLowerCase();
                    o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                });

            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration["Security:AuthorityUrl"];

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim("scope", Configuration["Security:ApiScope"]);
                });
            });

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"]);

            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyAPI", Version = "v1" });
            });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI v1"));
        }

        app.UseElmahIo();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
            endpoints.MapControllers()
                .RequireAuthorization("ApiScope");
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post some sample code (your API Program/Startup class)

Comment: It seems like probably the same question as this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579279/unauthorized-invalid-token-when-authenticating-with-jwt-bearer-token-after-upd

Also accepted answer is basically same as what I said.

Comment: Also the issue is discussed here, with same explanations and solution:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1792

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting 401s after updating to .net6 - specifically after switching from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 3.1.* to 6.0.*

I found this exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.InternalValidators.ValidateLifetimeAndIssuerAfterSignatureNotValidatedJwt(...
```

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/6.0.0#dependencies-body-tab) has a dependency on [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect/6.10.0#versions-body-tab) and bumps the reference from 5.5.0 - or 6.7.1 if you're coming from NET5 - to 6.10.0 - and all of it's dependencies like System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.

More precisely, issue is apparent for me when restoring versions 6.10.0 to 6.15.0 System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.

It turns out I had a reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens version 6.22.1 elsewhere in my project, and this causes Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens version 6.22.1 to be restored. Because of [this commit](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/commit/922901505740480f3fe6349e501ad36082e441e3) - which was released as part of version 6.15.1 -  Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens 6.15.1 and higher is not backwards compatible with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 6.15.0 and lower.

The solution - add some explicit reference(s) to the dependent packages to force them to restore versions 6.15.1 and higher:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.23.1" />
```

I have to wonder why Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer is still referencing such ancient versions of these dependenct libraries though. It is causes these old 18+ months old versions of these libraries to be massively more downloaded in total and per-week than new versions, above 6.10.0. Also as far as I understood it, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt is more-or-less deprecated by Microsoft at this point, I don't know why it's still being used internally e.g. in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.

As [MS states](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki) themselves:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens .... This is a newer, faster version
> of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt that has additional functionality.

EDIT: Additionally, you could fix this by moving to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer version 7.0.*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/7.0.0-preview.3.22178.4#dependencies-body-tab) since you can see, someone working on that project has also reaslized this problem and bumped the internal reference up to 6.15.1 - well that's still in preview at the moment and probably nobody is too keen to shift to anything 7.* Short-Term-Support at the moment in their projects anyway. They should update this reference in 6.* version also I think. It seems like many people had this problem.