# Why is JWTBearer in .net 6 not working? It keeps coming back with invalid_token

Tags: c#, jwt, bearer-token

(Environment: .net 6 web api)
reference post: [c# asp.net core Bearer error="invalid_token"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54395859/c-sharp-asp-net-core-bearer-error-invalid-token)
solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6143908/lancelot-lovejoy

I'm asking this question again because I do not have any points to comment on the original post, however, after spending 2 days on this I thought it was important to put this here:
Lancelot Lovejoy had it bang on, the order matters. wherever you're defining your app object...

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication(); // <-- first
app.UseAuthorization(); // <-- second
```

I don't know why the order matters, maybe someone can explain it to me, but I seriously lost 2 freaking days because of it. Hopefully, this will save someone that same time. Thank you a million times over Lancelot.

Comment: That’s the order of things happening. If you try to authorize without first authenticating it won’t work. These are middleware components and will run in the order introduced so order matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you always have to authentication to know who the user is. After that you do authorization to figure out if the user is authorized to access a given resource or not.

You can't determine what a user is allowed to do, if you don't know who it is. authentication is all about who is the user?

Just like my diagram here:
[image]

Here's a good video about it:
[Implementing Authorization in Web Applications and APIs - Brock Allen & Dominick Baier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-a7JbXL0hq0)

To help you about your token problem, then look in the logs, or perhaps also post more about how you have configured JwtBearer.